# How to bind checkbox to string value in Angular7?

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

`<input pInputText type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.active">`
active is a string. It's value is 'true' or 'false'. I wanna bind this string value to a checkbox.
So how can I do that?

Comment: Can't you parse it before you bind the value? And if backend requires it, parse it again before sending to the API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

not use "banana syntax"

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  [ngModel]="rowData.active=='true'?true:false"
  (ngModelChange)="rowData.active=$event?'true':'false'"
>
```

Comment: You can simplify the line:  [ngModel]="rowData.active=='true'?true:false" to   [ngModel]="rowData.active == 'true'"

Comment: @Victoria Really you're correct, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<input type="checkbox">`, then it is possible to use the following syntax  to bind:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
   [checked]="(rowData.active === 'true') ? true : false"
   (change)="rowData.active = $event.target.checked"
/>

<p> rowData.active {{ rowData.active }}</p>
```

TypeScript:

```
rowData = {active: 'true'};
```

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<input type='checkbox' [(ngModel)]='rowData.active'>
```

in ts

```
 rowData={'active' : true}
```

Working [StackBligz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzsvcs)

If you use primeng, ref [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use `get` and `set` in your component code. First use a dedicated variable in your HTML. `<input pInputText type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowIsActive">`. Then in your component add the following:

```
...

get rowIsActive(): boolean {
  return this.rowData.active !== '';
}

set rowIsActive($event: boolean) {
  return this.rowData.active = $event ? "true" : ""';
}
...
```

That way, you can still use the 'Banana in a box' syntax and reliably convert boolean to string values without the additional `(ngModelChange)`.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add `binary="true"` attribute in your HTMLElement.

As per my understanding you are using primeng's checkbox. So code should be like this -

```
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="rowData.active" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
```

For more in details read out the whole documentation here -

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox

Comment: It's not primeng checkbox. Just <input type="checkbox">.

Comment: why are you using like this? No sure about your intention. Either user `p-checkbox` or normal input type text.